# i want python xpath data-tip print

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, getattribute

I want to print the "data-tip" data here. but I couldn't do it anyway.

```
<div class="rightstats" id="my_cash"><div data-number="3044519" data-positions="6" class="val" data-val="2044519" data-tip="2&amp;nbsp;044&amp;nbsp;519 cash" data-mobiletip="1&amp;nbsp;973&amp;nbsp;762 cash">2&nbsp;M</div><div class="plus" onclick="show_dialog('shop_treasures');"></div></div>
```

```
cash= site.find_element("xpath","//*\[@id='my_cash'\]/div\[1\]")
time.sleep(1)
print ('cash= ', cash.text)
```

outputs

```
"2m"
```

I tried

```py
cash= site.find_element("xpath","//*\[@id='my_cash'\]/div\[1\]/@data-tip")
time.sleep(1)
print ('cash= ', cash.text)
```

I want to print the "data-tip" data here. but I couldn't do it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-tip` is not a text content but an attribute, so instead of `cash.text` you should apply `cash.get_attribute("data-tip")` here.
The entire code could be:

```py
cash= site.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='my_cash']/div[1]")
print('cash= ', cash.get_attribute("data-tip"))
```